# what is a quick way to delete all elements from a list that do not satisfy a constraint?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings. I have a function that given a string returns 0 or 1. How can I delete all strings in the list for which the function returns 0?

Answer (score 7):

```
[x for x in lst if fn(x) != 0]
```

This is a "list comprehension", one of Python's nicest pieces of syntactical sugar that often takes lines of code in other languages and additional variable declarations, etc.

See: 
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Note that this creates a new list; it doesn't mutate an existing list.

Comment: `if not fn(x)` is more idiomatic and works correctly with any value Python considers true/false (your function happens to return 0 or 1 but there is no reason to hardcode this assumption).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a generator expression over a list comprehension to avoid a potentially large, intermediate list.

```
result = (x for x in l if f(x))
# print it, or something
print list(result)
```

Like a list comprehension, this will not modify your original list, in place.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: see the bottom for the best answer.

If you need to mutate an existing list, for example because you have another reference to it somewhere else, you'll need to actually `remove` the values from the list.

I'm not aware of any such function in Python, but something like this would work (untested code):

```
def cull_list(lst, pred):
    """Removes all values from ``lst`` which for which ``pred(v)`` is false."""
    def remove_all(v):
        """Remove all instances of ``v`` from ``lst``"""
        try:
             while True:
                 lst.remove(v)
        except ValueError:
             pass

    values = set(lst)

    for v in values:
        if not pred(v):
            remove_all(v)
```

A probably more-efficient alternative that may look a bit too much like C code for some people's taste:

```
def efficient_cull_list(lst, pred):
    end = len(lst)
    i = 0
    while i < end:
        if not pred(lst[i]):
            del lst[i]
            end -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
```

**edit...**: as Aaron pointed out in the comments, this can be done much more cleanly with something like

```
def reversed_cull_list(lst, pred):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
        if not pred(lst[i]):
            del lst[i]
```

**...edit**

The trick with these routines is that using a function like `enumerate`, as suggested by (an) other responder(s), will not take into account the fact that elements of the list have been removed.  The only way (that I know of) to do that is to just track the index manually instead of allowing python to do the iteration.  There's bound to be a speed compromise there, so it may end up being better just to do something like

```
lst[:] = (v for v in lst if pred(v))
```

Actually, now that I think of it, this is by far the most sensible way to do an 'in-place' filter on a list.  The generator's values are iterated before filling `lst`'s elements with them, so there are no index conflict issues.  If you want to make this more explicit just do

```
lst[:] = [v for v in lst if pred(v)]
```

I don't think it will make much difference in this case, in terms of efficiency.

Either of these last two approaches will, if I understand correctly how they actually work, make an extra copy of the list, so one of the bona fide in-place solutions mentioned above would be better if you're dealing with some "huge tracts of land."

Comment: `enumerate` does seem to adjust indexes appropriately.  I didn't think that it did until I tried it.  Write a simple loop over a list from 1 to 20 that removes every item that is an even multiple of 3.  Print the list and index every time that you do a removal.  You will remove indexes 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, and 12.

Comment: you can make the loop simpler by looping over it in reverse. Then when you delete an element, you don't have to decrement (or even have) `end`.  Also, no branch in the while.

Comment: @D.Shawley: Either you're confused or I am.  I wrote some [doctests](http://gist.github.com/618883) to test the various presented solutions to this question; maybe I got something wrong with that?

Comment: @Aaron: ah, very good point.  I added a reversed-order indexed version.

Comment: @D.Shawley: repeat your experiment with a predicate that specifies every item that is NOT an even multiple of 3.

Comment: Yup. `reversed` is required.  The generator solution is probably the nicest except that it doesn't modify the list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> def f(x):             
...     if x<=2: return 0
...     else: return 1   
>>> for n,x in enumerate(s):
...     if f(x) == 0: s[n]=None
>>> s=filter(None,s)
>>> s
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This doesn't work: for the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `f = lambda v: v <= 2` I get `[1, 2, 4, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

With a generator expression:

```
alist[:] = (item for item in alist if afunction(item))
```

Functional:

```
alist[:] = filter(afunction, alist)
```

or:

```
import itertools
alist[:] = itertools.ifilter(afunction, alist)
```

All equivalent.

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
alist = [item for item in alist if afunction(item)]
```

An in-place modification:

```
import collections

indexes_to_delete= collections.deque(
    idx
    for idx, item in enumerate(alist)
    if afunction(item))
while indexes_to_delete:
    del alist[indexes_to_delete.pop()]
```